# Speed up extracting Zip-Files

Tags: java, zip, java-8

I programmed a little example of working with zip-files in java. Actually I'm wondering, if there is a faster way to extract such a file. If i'm testing my tool with bigger files(Like 1GB or more) the process takes really to long. 
I'm thankful for every advice.

Im doing it like this:

```
    private void extractFolder(String zipFile, String extractFolder)
{
    try
    {
        int BUFFER = 2048;
        File file = new File(zipFile);

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
        String newPath = extractFolder;

        new File(newPath).mkdir();
        Enumeration zipFiles = zip.entries();

        while (zipFiles.hasMoreElements())
        {

            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFiles.nextElement();
            String currentEntry = entry.getName();

            File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
            // destFile = new File(newPath, destFile.getName());
            File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

            // create the parent directory structure if needed
            destinationParent.mkdirs();

            if (!entry.isDirectory())
            {
                BufferedInputStream inputSteam = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry));
                int currentByte;
                // init buffer
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutSteam = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream, BUFFER);

                while ((currentByte = inputSteam.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)
                {
                    bufferedOutSteam.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }

                bufferedOutSteam.flush();
                outStream.flush();

                bufferedOutSteam.close();
                inputSteam.close();
                outStream.close();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, are you using Java 7+? If yes consider using the zip filesystem provider instead

Comment: @fge yeah actually i'm using java 8

Comment: The easiest improvement would be to increase the buffer size. 2048 bytes is nothing. Use 10 megabytes, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that is not precisely the answer you are waiting for but you want to try [this package](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more); with the latest stable version your code can be "reduced" to this (note that the destination directory **must not** exist):

```
final Path zipFile = Paths.get("path/to/file.zip");
final Path dstDir = Paths.get("path/to/destination/directory");

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = MoreFileSystems.openZip(zipFile, true);
) {
    MoreFiles.copyRecursize(zipfs.getPath("/"), dstDir,
        RecursionMode.FAIL_FAST);
}
```

This will use the JRE's provided zip filesystem provider; it may or may not be optimized for your use case (I haven't checked!).

Javadoc links:

- [`MoreFileSystems.openZip()`](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/MoreFileSystems.html#openZip(java.nio.file.Path,%20boolean));
- [`MoreFiles.copyRecursive()`](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/MoreFiles.html#copyRecursive(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20com.github.fge.filesystem.RecursionMode,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

Comment: Thanks i will have a look at it!